# Finding the total amount of space allowed for user's mailbox and remaining space

Tags: imap

Can anybody help me out to find the total amount of space allocted and used space using php imap ?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[`imap_mailboxmsginfo`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-mailboxmsginfo.php)** or **[`imap_get_quotaroot`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-get-quotaroot.php)**:

***Return Values:***

```
Date          date of last change (current datetime)
Driver        driver
Mailbox       name of the mailbox
Nmsgs         number of messages
Recent        number of recent messages
Unread        number of unread messages
Deleted       number of deleted messages
Size          mailbox size
```

***[imap_mailboxmsginfo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-mailboxmsginfo.php)***:

```
<?php

$mbox = imap_open("{imap.example.org}INBOX", "username", "password")
      or die("can't connect: " . imap_last_error());

$check = imap_mailboxmsginfo($mbox);

if ($check) {
    echo "Date: "     . $check->Date    . "<br />\n" ;
    echo "Driver: "   . $check->Driver  . "<br />\n" ;
    echo "Mailbox: "  . $check->Mailbox . "<br />\n" ;
    echo "Messages: " . $check->Nmsgs   . "<br />\n" ;
    echo "Recent: "   . $check->Recent  . "<br />\n" ;
    echo "Unread: "   . $check->Unread  . "<br />\n" ;
    echo "Deleted: "  . $check->Deleted . "<br />\n" ;
    echo "Size: "     . $check->Size    . "<br />\n" ;
} else {
    echo "imap_mailboxmsginfo() failed: " . imap_last_error() . "<br />\n";
}

imap_close($mbox);

?>
```

***[imap_get_quotaroot](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-get-quotaroot.php)***:

```
<?php
$mbox = imap_open("{imap.example.org}", "kalowsky", "password", OP_HALFOPEN)
      or die("can't connect: " . imap_last_error());

$quota = imap_get_quotaroot($mbox, "INBOX");
if (is_array($quota)) {
   $storage = $quota['STORAGE'];
   echo "STORAGE usage level is: " .  $storage['usage'];
   echo "STORAGE limit level is: " .  $storage['limit'];

   $message = $quota['MESSAGE'];
   echo "MESSAGE usage level is: " .  $message['usage'];
   echo "MESSAGE limit level is: " .  $message['limit'];

   /* ...  */

}

imap_close($mbox);
?>
```

***[imap_get_quota](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-get-quota.php)***: (admin)

```
<?php
$mbox = imap_open("{imap.example.org}", "mailadmin", "password", OP_HALFOPEN)
      or die("can't connect: " . imap_last_error());

$quota_value = imap_get_quota($mbox, "user.kalowsky");
if (is_array($quota_value)) {
    echo "Usage level is: " . $quota_value['usage'];
    echo "Limit level is: " . $quota_value['limit'];
}

imap_close($mbox);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks l'L'l, it really helped me